# Magento 2 error message when customer login failed (f.e. wrong password)

Tags: magento2, error, login, messages

How can I output an error message on login page if customer input wrong password? I use default login-template but no error message is shown ...

Thanks!
Martin

Comment: I need default message "You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled." - it is not shown on wrong login datas?

Answer (score 0):

... found issue ... my theme had custom messages.phtml which was not correkt. just added code from default messages.phtml and it works